# What sort of hip bone is required for quadrupedal animals to locomote on their hind legs?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, xenobiology, skeletons, bones

I am designing a creature that is quadrupedal but can run after prey on its hind legs. What kind of hip bone would allow for the excess stress to be put on it during bipedal locomotion? The animal is roughly the size of a mountain lion and weighs on average 100 pounds. It is a predatory carnivore. The planet it inhabits in very similar to Earth. It has an identical atmosphere that is 23% oxygen.

Comment: Have you already looked at the structure of real life animals that exhibit a similar mode of locomotion? An example would be hadrosaurs, which usually moved on four legs but ran bipedally.

Comment: I have tried that but I couldn't find a good diagram of the hip.

Comment: Your oxygen content concern looks like a good separate question.

Comment: Two rules for oxygen. Be somewhere between 0.16 and 0.5 atm for human breathability. But you can never have more than 35 % of the total atmosphere as oxygen, because above that concentration fires will never stop burning. This results in runaway wildfires bringing the oxygen content down to 35% again. Of cause the latter rule only applies if you desire to have a biosphere.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight Thanks soo much, I'll update the question with this data!

Comment: This means you'll have 0.35 atm O2 should you insist on earthlike pressure. Should you want to go for the maximum breathable O2 content of 0.5 atm, the total pressure will be 1.43 atm. Be aware that fire will be viciously dangerous on your world.

Comment: This largely depends on how they move on two legs, are they vertical like kangaroo or upright like humans. in the former case not much has to change in the latter a lot has to change.

Comment: @John It would run on its hindlimbs vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For vertical [facultative-bipeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facultative_bipedalism) (Adapted primarily for walking on four legs, but able to walk on two legs) the only real consideration they have is where the center of gravity.

Bipeds need the center of gravity directly over the feet, otherwise they fall over, that is why in facultative-bipeds like kangaroo and some hadrosaurs have small front limbs and large tails it moves the center of gravity as close to the hips as possible. Basically anything the animal can do to move the center of gravity this way helps.

What exactly will help depends on what their anatomy and pelvic anatomy in particular is like overall. note that although the front limbs are skinny they are still close to the same length as the back limbs otherwise they cannot walk on all fours. If you look at hadrosaurs it looks like their front limbs are very short but they are the only dinosaur with free floating shoulders so the shoulder blades add to the limb length.

the limbs proportions also look different because the hind limb  has to be able to support the entire weight of the animal while the front limbs only need to be able to support a a fraction of the weight. that is why dinosaurs also have larger pelvises compared to mammals, they need to be stronger and attack more muscle.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The dinosaur *Iguanodon* comes to mind, and looking up `iguanodon hip` gave me these images

[image: Specific to the hip]

and

[image: Full skeleton]

I hope this helps.

Comment: *Deinonychus* was a raptor genus, pretty quick, and the larger species were right in the size range the querent is after.  There is also some evidence they may have been the smartest of all the dinosaurs.

Comment: Yes, but is there a belief that *Deinonychus* went on all fours @ZeissIkon? That might be good for, say a skull, but maybe not too god for the hip

Comment: Ah, missed the "usually quadripedal" qualification.

Answer (score 2):

So, what you're asking for is called a facultative biped. There are many, many types of animals which are facultatively bipedal, even more than there are obligately bipedal animals. Some examples include pangolins, agamids, iguanas, sifakas, ornithopod dinosaurs, a lot of basal archosaurs like rauisuchians, prosauropods, ground sloths, chalicotheres, monitor lizards, beavers, raccoons, skunks, gibbons, indris, *Eudibamus*, baby sauropods, stegosaurs, tree kangaroos, and even cockroaches.

What's important here isn't the structure of the hip, but rather the distribution of mass. The main reason why the average quadruped can't walk on two legs is that too much of its mass needs its forelegs for support. If you have an animal where most of the weight is directly above the hips and hindlimbs, which never leave the ground, then you're good. Also, the hind legs should be longer than the forelegs.

Answer (score 1):

There are lizard species that do this. For example *Chlamydosaurus kingii*, the Northern Australian Frilled Dragon that runs two-legged on land

**Video:** https://youtu.be/XAo09yYOpCU?t=29

[image]

---

and *Basiliscus basiliscus*, the Jesus Christ Lizard that can run on *water*!

**Video:** https://youtu.be/45yabrnryXk?t=40

[image]